# if-statement: how to rewrite in matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, combinations

I'm newby in Matlab. I have took the work code with complex `if-statement` condition and need to rewrite it. This code should prepare some initial data to solve an optimization task. This `if-statement` condition looks like:

```
x=[784.8 959.2 468 572 279 341 139.5 170.5 76.5 93.5 45 55];
a=nchoosek(x,6); % all possible combinations from 6 elements of x
n=length(a);
q=[];

 for i=1:n

if( ((a(i,1)==x(1)) & (a(i,2)==x(2))) | 
    ((a(i,1)==x(3)) & (a(i,2)==x(4))) | 
    ((a(i,1)==x(5)) & (a(i,2)==x(6))) |  
    ((a(i,1)==x(7)) & (a(i,2)==x(8))) |
    ((a(i,2)==x(3)) & (a(i,3)==x(4))) |  
    ((a(i,2)==x(5)) & (a(i,3)==x(6))) | 
    ((a(i,2)==x(7)) & (a(i,3)==x(8))) |  
    ((a(i,3)==x(3)) & (a(i,4)==x(4))) |  
    ((a(i,3)==x(5)) & (a(i,4)==x(6))) |  
    ((a(i,3)==x(7)) & (a(i,4)==x(8))) |  
    ((a(i,3)==x(9)) & (a(i,4)==x(10)))|  
    ((a(i,4)==x(5)) & (a(i,5)==x(6))) |  
    ((a(i,4)==x(7)) & (a(i,5)==x(8))) |  
    ((a(i,4)==x(9)) & (a(i,5)==x(10)))|  
    ((a(i,5)==x(5)) & (a(i,6)==x(6))) |  
    ((a(i,5)==x(7)) & (a(i,6)==x(8))) |  
    ((a(i,5)==x(9)) & (a(i,6)==x(10)) | 
    ((a(i,5)==x(11)) & (a(i,6)==x(12)))))
   q(i,:)=a(i,:);
end;
end;
q;
R1=a-q;
R1(~any(R1,2),:) = [];
R1(:, ~any(R1)) = [];
```

**Question:** Could anyone give an idea how to rewrite `if-statement` to improve readability of code?

Comment: That forest of conditions will be nearly impossible for anybody but you to simplify; there's no meaning behind all those components. One suggestion, however: use logical rather than bit operations, since the former will short-circuit (probably), while the latter won't.

Comment: Also note that your last line is a single OR case, while the previous lines contain 2 cases each. This is far from trivial from the sectioning of your conditons (I'd use a single top-level OR per line), and might even be an error on your side.

Comment: Final point: if you are comparing permutations of an array with another array, why not generate indices rather than the values themselves, in which case you can test equality of integers (rather than who-knows-whats)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak, thanks for your comment, espesiall for the final point, I don't think about the generation indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, what the convoluted if statement basically says

```
If "x(1) x(2)" or "x(3) x(4)" or ... "x(11) x(12)" appears anywhere consecutively in row i
```

Think about it:

```
((a(i,1)==x(1)) & (a(i,2)==x(2))) |  ((a(i,1)==x(3)) & (a(i,2)==x(4))) |
((a(i,1)==x(5)) & (a(i,2)==x(6))) |   ((a(i,1)==x(7)) & (a(i,2)==x(8)))
```

is no different from:

```
((a(i,1)==x(1)) & (a(i,2)==x(2))) |  ((a(i,1)==x(3)) & (a(i,2)==x(4))) |
((a(i,1)==x(5)) & (a(i,2)==x(6))) |   ((a(i,1)==x(7)) & (a(i,2)==x(8))) |
((a(i,1)==x(9)) & (a(i,2)==x(10))) |   ((a(i,1)==x(11)) & (a(i,2)==x(12)))
```

since `[x(9) x(10)]` and `[x(11) x(12)]` will never appear at `a(i, 1:2)`, so the line I added is always false and does not change the result of the chain of OR's. But if makes the logic much easier to understand. Same logic applies to `a(i,2:3), a(i,3:4)...`, complete those cases too and then you will get the first statement I made in this answer.

Then, instead of generating `a` directly from `x`, you should generate `a` from the **INDEX** of `x`, i.e. `[1:12]`, as such:

```
a = nchoosek(1:length(x), 6);
```

Why? You said `x` consists of real numbers, and using `==` on real numbers does not guarantee success, and is a very bad practice in general.

Then, your target becomes:

```
find if sequence `[1 2]` or `[3 4]` or `[5 6]` ... exists in each line of `a`
```

which is equivalent to:

```
find if there is any odd number n followed by n+1
```

This logic can be represented as:

```
success = any (mod(a(:,1:end-1), 2) & diff(a,1,2)==1, 2)
```

Now `success(i)` will be `true/false` for the every `a(i)` that your statement evaluates to the same value. This method is better than your statement because it is very concise, automatically adapts to different sizes of `x` and does not need to run in a loop.

And if you want to get the actual combination of `x` values, just do

```
x(a(i));    % Get the ith permutation of x
x(a);       % Get all permutation of x
x(a(success,:));    % Get all permutation of x that satisfy the requirement.
```

**EDIT:**

```
q = a;               % q is basically a copy of a
q(~success,:) = 0;   % except the `non-success` rows are zero 
x(q) - x(a)          % suppose q and a store index, this will give you the substraction.
```

Comment: thanks you for the full answer but I can't accept your solution. I have updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, it should be any(..., 2). I have updated my answer